# Save image with pure Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

**Very simple:** How do I save an image with pure Flash only?

---

**Example code:**

```
var bitmap: BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100, true, 0);
bitmap.draw(this);
var data: ByteArray = bitmap.getPixels(bitmap.rect);
var f: FileReference = new FileReference();
f.save(data, "test.bmp");
```

This saves me a file of 40,000 bytes (`4 * 100 * 100`). I checked it with hex editor and it **is** the pixels of my bitmap/sprite. Now I don't care what image type comes out of this. I just want it saved in a format that I can display with common image editors. I don't want to install extra stuff. Can I do it with Flash only, no AIR, no JPGEncoder, no nothing extra?

*(This function is not for customers to use anyways.)*

Comment: How about the [PNGEncoder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/codec/PNGEncoder.html) ? And your question is kinda confusing, does the bmp get correctly saved or not?

Comment: @DodgerThud Only the pixels get saved, no width or height of image, no bitmap headers. I just checked carefully. And PNGEncoder is not present on my system so it belongs to all the extra stuff.

Comment: So, can you look at the .bmp with an image editor? If you want to convert it to another file, you won't get around using extra stuff

Comment: @DodgerThud No, the image can't be displayed because there is no info about width and height for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
First off, you need to make sure that you are targeting a Flash Player with at least version 11.3, and compile the SWF with at least a version of 18 (or at least, 18 worked for me).

The BitmapData Class has its own method called `encode` which will handle the encoding work for you, either for JPEG or PNG. Here is how to do it:

```
var bitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100,100,true,0);
bitmap.draw(this);
var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var o:PNGEncoderOptions = new PNGEncoderOptions();
bitmap.encode(bitmap.rect, o, data);
var f:FileReference= new FileReference();
f.save(data, "test.png");
```

The third parameter of `encode` is the output Bytearray where the encoded Bytearray will get saved.

[AS3 Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#encode())

Comment: Surprisingly it works. I thought anything starting with "PNGEncoder" or "JPEGEncoder" means a death sentence but both option classes are available and encoding works too, although I don't have access to the encoder classes themselves. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I just found this by accident myself just now, looking through the Docs. You should be cautious though, I think this uses the same stuff like PNGEncoder (and JPGEncoder), so it is slow and will lock up your UI Thread if you encode very large images.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use PNGEncoder or JPGEncoder and still be "pure flash". If you're missing the libraries you can get them (and others) in the [as3corelib swc library](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib). Just include the swc in your library path.

If for some reason it's not pure enough, I suppose you could always go in to the source code of the library and copy out the specific PNGEncoder or JPGEncoder class and repurpose it for your uses.